# Ошибка в коде элемента 2D инвентаря

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Ошибка:

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'RectTransform' attached to the
>   "0" game object, but a script is trying to access it. You probably
>   need to add a RectTransform to the game object "0". Or your script
>   needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
>   UnityEngine.Transform.set_localPosition (UnityEngine.Vector3 value)
>   <0x17df66e0 + 0x0005a> in <5350b2ecf18c4d938d283fb54ae35614>:0
>   Inventory.AddGraphics () (at Assets/Scripts/Inventory.cs:90)
>   Inventory.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Inventory.cs:31)

Код:

```
public void AddGraphics()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++)
    {
        GameObject newItem = Instantiate(gameObject, InventoryMainObject.transform) as GameObject;

        newItem.name = i.ToString();

        ItemInventory ii = new ItemInventory();
        ii.itemGameObj = newItem;

        RectTransform rt = newItem.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        rt.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0); // МЕСТО ОШИБКИ
        rt.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        newItem.GetComponentInChildren<RectTransform>().localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);

        Button tempButtton = newItem.GetComponent<Button>();

        tempButtton.onClick.AddListener(delegate { SelectObject(); });

        items.Add(ii);
    }
}
```

Comment: Судя по ошибке, объект "newItem" не содержит компонент "RectTransform".

Answer (score 1):

Компонент `RectTransform` есть только у объектов `Canvas`, типа `UI.Image`, `UI.Text` или `UI.Button`. У `GameObject` его нет, обычный `Transform`.